# How to get distribution function

Tags: probability, integration, probability-theory, probability-distributions, density-function

I have a density function $g(x,y)=4xy \mathbb{I}_{[0,1]\times[0,1] }(x,y)$. How can I get a distribution function $G(x,y)$?

I found that $G(x,y)= \int _{-\infty}^x \int _{-\infty}^y f(u,v) du dv$ where $f(u,v)$ is density function and $G(x,y)$ distribution function. I this right? How can I use it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$G(x,y)=\int_0^{x}\int_0^{y} 4uv du dv=x^{2}y^{2}$ for $0\leq x,y \leq 1$. For $0\leq x \leq 1$ and $y >1$ we have $G(x,y)=\int_0^{x}\int_0^{1} 4uv du dv=x^{2}$ and for  $0\leq y \leq 1$ and $x >1$ we have $G(x,y)=y^{2}$. Finally $G(x,y) =1$ if $x,y >1$ and $0$ of $x,y<0$.

Comment: Could you explain me why you took those intervals for example if $0\geq x, y \geq 1$ you took integrals $\int_0^x \int_0^y$?

Comment: Since $g(x,y)=0$ if $x<0$ or $y<0$ all integrals start from $0$. If $x>1$ then the integral from $0$ to $x$ becomes integral from $0$ to $1$ because the density function vanishes for outside $[0,1]$ so it makes no contribution to the integral from $1$ to $x$, etc.